# cx_freeze python sqlite3 database doesn't work after build.exe?

Tags: python, sqlite, cx-freeze, qsqldatabase

Basically i have a pyqt application that uses a sqlite3 database, now I used Cx_Freeze to turn it into an executable.

I find that the database and queries run perfectly when they are ran as a .py, but after the cx_freeze conversion to .exe the gui works flawlessly but the database doesn't respond to any queries.

Here is the code for the setup script:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = [],
    excludes = [],
    includes = ["sip", "PyQt5.QtSql"],
    include_files = ["tpaData.db"])

import sys
base = 'Win32GUI' if sys.platform=='win32' else None

executables = [Executable('testTpa.py', base=base)]

setup(
    name='Tpa APP',
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'A PyQt TPA Program',
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
    executables = executables
)
```

here is the code I use to instantiate the db and app:

```
def __init__(self, dialog):
        Ui_Form.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(dialog)
        self.createConnection()

def createConnection(self):
        self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.db.setDatabaseName("tpaData.db")
        self.db.open()
        self.query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
        self.query.exec_("create table doses(dose text, bolus text, discard text, remaining text, time1 text, time2 text, time3 text, comment text)")
```

later in the app i use the query.prepare method to make a string of the inputs and then query.bind method to bind values to the query.prepare string. Finally i use query.exec_() to submit that prepared string.

In the dev environment(.py file) works, just post cx_freeze it fails.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**cx_freeze** does not copy the folder with the drivers for the library databases. If you copy them for example from "*C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\sqldrivers*" with the directory "*sqldrivers*" in your build directory should work. I have a similar case, but with **PySide** - it worked.

Comment: I will give pyside a try as it is pretty close to qt4. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the solution to my problems here, just used py2exe or pyinstaller to make the distributable, apparently the Cx_freeze version I was using was not compatible with my version of python.